# Trying to perfect my render by adding imperfections

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

My render is coming up amazingly well, but I want to take it to the next level by adding welding marks whenever the objects meet. I found a couple of videos on YouTube, but I was wondering if there's any way of accomplishing the same automatically with geometry nodes.

[image]

Comment: if you're using Cycles there's the Bevel node that you can use in the Shader Editor, this is node geometry node though

Comment: Have a look at Blender Welder Addon.